# How to access json in javascript after rendering it in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

If I render json in Ruby, how do I access the values in javascript?

In ruby, if I write:

```
response = {:key => "val"}
response = response.to_json
render :json => response, :status => 200
```

How would I access "val" in javascript?

If I do alert(response) in javascript, I see a  tag surrounding the json, does this make a difference or is this expected?

I tried jQuery.parseJSON(response) but I got a syntax error. If I try to access response directly, I don't get the correct value- should

`response.key === "val"`

evaluate to true?

Am I setting it up incorrectly in Ruby or accessing it incorrectly in javascript, or both?

Comment: Please show the javascript code.

Comment: It's basically just if(response.key === "val") {...}, but it evaluates to false and I'm not sure why. I thought it may have been because of the <pre> tags but maybe that just happens when alert() is used. I'm mostly unsure whether I need to parseJSON or if it's already JSON.

Comment: The response should be got at the ajax callback function, what did you do?

Comment: At that function, the first thing I do is that if statement and it does not return the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you could show your javascript code.
Anyway, one way you can do it is to use jQuery's ajax function and set the dataType to json.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<your link>",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.key)
        alert(response.key);
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example.

In ./config/routes.rb

```
match '/index' => 'application#index'
match '/json' => 'application#json'
```

The controller, ./app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def index
    # server side code required by index
  end

  def json
    response = {:key => "val"}
    response = response.to_json
    render :json => response, :status => 200
  end
end
```

The erb page an ajax request is made from, in this case ./app/views/application/index.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $("a#my_ajax").bind("ajax:success",
                function(evt, data, status, xhr){
                    console.log(data.key);
                    console.log(data.key === "val");
                }).bind("ajax:error", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
                    console.log("doh!")
                });
    });
</script>

<%= link_to "test",  {:controller=>"application",  :action => 'json'}, :remote=> true, :id => "my_ajax" %>
```